# array map is not a function in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Usually, it works, but right now it shows an error.

componentDidMount code

```
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_URL}/admins/playlist_admin`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': this.state.token
            }
        })
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({ list: res.data.response });
            })
    }
```

Render code

```
<MynTable headData={headData} className="bg-blue text-white myn-table" >
                            {
                                list ? //i checked in console. list has some data 
                                    list.map((playlist, index) =>
                                    (
                                        <tr key={index}>
                                            <td>{playlist.id}</td>
                                            <td>{playlist.name}</td>
                                            <td>{playlist.songs.length}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ))
                                    : null
                            }
                        </MynTable>
```

Data is coming from APIs and got saved in the state still map function show error of map is not a function. if a changed the express list ? with list.length > 0 ? then error is removed but again render didn't return anything.

Comment: Are you sure `list` is not an object instead of array?

Comment: check type of `list` array or something else?

Comment: The code you've shown is fine (assuming `list` comes from `this.state`). If it's an intermittent problem, that tells you that somewhere, you're setting `list` to something that isn't an array. That could be because the response to the GET is coming back with something other than an array for `res.data.response`, or it could be some other `setState` somewhere else.

Comment: You are storing the ai response in the state which is a object, the list may be an array.

Comment: *"i checked in console. list has some data"* Even if it were an empty array, `map` would be fine. The problem is that somewhere, you're setting `list` to a non-array.

Comment: Stack overflow is a **very** active place. When you post a question (or an answer!), please *stick around* so you can respond to things that come up in the comments from people trying to help you.

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable suggestion. you are right. a list is actually an object and I am using it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an array called `list` which exists in your `store` object but in the JSX segment, you didn't check the existence properly.

###### Wrong implementation:

```
if(list) {
  return list.map()
} else {
  return null
}

// or with ternary operator:
list ? list.map() : null
```

##### Explanation:

As you see above, the if condition will check the `list` property which is a present property on the `state` (since the `list` property exists before the API call). So, checking the `list` with the above methods always will return `true`. to solve the issue, instead of checking the `list` before mapping, try to check the length of it.

##### The Solution:

```
{
  list.length > 0 ? list.map() : null
}
```

**Note:** you can use a short circuit for the above statement since the one side is null:

```
{
  list.length > 0 && list.map()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I fixed this problem with a loading indicator.

`componentDidMount()` is going to call after render - that's why you are getting this error.

You have to make a loading state set to true with a condition in render if loading is false going to map data.

Set loading to false in `componentDidMount()` after getting data to make sure that state is filled with data after that going to map it.